# How to store url as unique index in a 100% collision proof way?

Tags: mysql, database, hash, unique-index

I want be able to make a big mysql `INSERT` that ignore insert when the url already exists in the database. It will be done with `ON DUPLICATE KEY`.

But for that, I need to make the `url` column to a unique index.

I did that by creating a new column, called `url_hash`, where I store a MD5 hashed version of the url, and making that column unique instead.

The only problem is that, after doing this, I thought about how MD5 could work. And I realized that it can't possibly be 100% collision proof. The hashes are not 100% guaranteed to be unique. Even if the risk i small it would collide.

That made me start thinking if this actually is the best way to do this. To have a hash-value as a unique key for this purpose.

Is there any way to store the url as an unique index in an 100% collision proof way?

Comment: `md5` is not unique, in fact it's quiet un-unique, now. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Comment: All hash algorithms are, by definition, not collision-proof, because of the pigeonhole principle.  However, the odds of an inadvertent collision are very low, even with md5.

Answer (score 1):

Probability of just two hashes accidentally colliding is **2<sup>64</sup>** hashes, so you are pretty safe. If you want to secure yourself anyway, use `SHA2()` - there is still no collision found for this algorithm.

Comment: reference: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/are-there-any-known-collisions-for-the-sha-2-family-of-hash-functions

Answer (score 1):

Unless you store the url as it is, there probably is no 100% proof way, but you can get somewhat closer to 100% by adding an additional index column. For example you could store the length of the url or a second hash, created with a different hash function.